# Hi I'm trying to make a Loading Screen with Text using SVG. But every time the text doesn't get where I want it, it gets behind the Website Logo

Tags: html, svg

Can someone help me solve this problem i tried alone for a few hours and I didn't find any answer.
I made the Text in Figma and then I copied it to SVG.

This is the Code im using.
The text always goes behind the logo, not where I want it

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMiGa.png)

```html
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" id="line">
        <g fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" fill-opacity="0" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
          <path d="M11.52 0V92.16C11.52 95.04 12.096 97.248 13.248 98.784C14.496 100.32 15.84 101.472 17.28 102.24C19.008 103.104 20.928 103.584 23.04 103.68H57.6V115.2H23.04C17.28 115.2 12.816 114 9.648 111.6C6.576 109.2 4.32 106.56 2.88 103.68C1.152 100.32 0.192 96.48 0 92.16V0H11.52Z" fill="white"/>
          <path d="M79.1606 92.16C79.1606 95.328 80.2646 98.064 82.4726 100.368C84.7766 102.576 87.5126 103.68 90.6806 103.68H102.201C105.369 103.68 108.057 102.576 110.265 100.368C112.569 98.064 113.721 95.328 113.721 92.16V86.4H79.1606V92.16ZM125.241 92.16C125.241 95.328 124.617 98.304 123.369 101.088C122.217 103.872 120.585 106.32 118.473 108.432C116.361 110.544 113.913 112.224 111.129 113.472C108.345 114.624 105.369 115.2 102.201 115.2H90.6806C87.5126 115.2 84.5366 114.624 81.7526 113.472C78.9686 112.224 76.5206 110.544 74.4086 108.432C72.2966 106.32 70.6166 103.872 69.3686 101.088C68.2166 98.304 67.6406 95.328 67.6406 92.16V74.88H113.721C113.721 71.712 112.569 69.024 110.265 66.816C108.057 64.512 105.369 63.36 102.201 63.36H73.4006V51.84H102.201C105.369 51.84 108.345 52.464 111.129 53.712C113.913 54.864 116.361 56.496 118.473 58.608C120.585 60.72 122.217 63.168 123.369 65.952C124.617 68.736 125.241 71.712 125.241 74.88V92.16Z" fill="white"/>
          <path d="M181.08 92.16V74.88C181.08 71.712 179.928 69.024 177.624 66.816C175.416 64.512 172.728 63.36 169.56 63.36H158.04C154.872 63.36 152.136 64.512 149.832 66.816C147.624 69.024 146.52 71.712 146.52 74.88V92.16C146.52 95.328 147.624 98.064 149.832 100.368C152.136 102.576 154.872 103.68 158.04 103.68H169.56C172.728 103.68 175.416 102.576 177.624 100.368C179.928 98.064 181.08 95.328 181.08 92.16ZM192.6 120.96C192.6 124.128 191.976 127.104 190.728 129.888C189.576 132.672 187.944 135.12 185.832 137.232C183.72 139.344 181.272 140.976 178.488 142.128C175.704 143.376 172.728 144 169.56 144H140.76V132.48H169.56C172.728 132.48 175.416 131.328 177.624 129.024C179.928 126.816 181.08 124.128 181.08 120.96V112.032C177.624 114.144 173.784 115.2 169.56 115.2H158.04C154.872 115.2 151.896 114.624 149.112 113.472C146.328 112.224 143.88 110.544 141.768 108.432C139.656 106.32 137.976 103.872 136.728 101.088C135.576 98.304 135 95.328 135 92.16V74.88C135 71.712 135.576 68.736 136.728 65.952C137.976 63.168 139.656 60.72 141.768 58.608C143.88 56.496 146.328 54.864 149.112 53.712C151.896 52.464 154.872 51.84 158.04 51.84H169.56C172.728 51.84 175.704 52.464 178.488 53.712C181.272 54.864 183.72 56.496 185.832 58.608C187.944 60.624 189.576 63.024 190.728 65.808C191.976 68.592 192.6 71.568 192.6 74.736V120.96Z"></path>
          <path d="M250.971 92.16V74.88C250.971 71.712 249.819 69.024 247.515 66.816C245.307 64.512 242.619 63.36 239.451 63.36H227.931C224.763 63.36 222.027 64.512 219.723 66.816C217.515 69.024 216.411 71.712 216.411 74.88V92.16C216.411 95.328 217.515 98.064 219.723 100.368C222.027 102.576 224.763 103.68 227.931 103.68H239.451C242.619 103.68 245.307 102.576 247.515 100.368C249.819 98.064 250.971 95.328 250.971 92.16ZM262.491 92.16C262.491 95.328 261.867 98.304 260.619 101.088C259.467 103.872 257.835 106.32 255.723 108.432C253.611 110.544 251.163 112.224 248.379 113.472C245.595 114.624 242.619 115.2 239.451 115.2H227.931C224.763 115.2 221.787 114.624 219.003 113.472C216.219 112.224 213.771 110.544 211.659 108.432C209.547 106.32 207.867 103.872 206.619 101.088C205.467 98.304 204.891 95.328 204.891 92.16V74.88C204.891 71.712 205.467 68.736 206.619 65.952C207.867 63.168 209.547 60.72 211.659 58.608C213.771 56.496 216.219 54.864 219.003 53.712C221.787 52.464 224.763 51.84 227.931 51.84H239.451C242.619 51.84 245.595 52.464 248.379 53.712C251.163 54.864 253.611 56.496 255.723 58.608C257.835 60.72 259.467 63.168 260.619 65.952C261.867 68.736 262.491 71.712 262.491 74.88V92.16Z"></path>
          <path d="M303.154 63.36C299.986 63.36 297.25 64.512 294.946 66.816C292.738 69.024 291.634 71.712 291.634 74.88V92.16C291.634 95.328 291.01 98.304 289.762 101.088C288.61 103.872 286.978 106.32 284.866 108.432C282.754 110.544 280.306 112.224 277.522 113.472C274.738 114.624 271.762 115.2 268.594 115.2V103.68C271.762 103.68 274.45 102.576 276.658 100.368C278.962 98.064 280.114 95.328 280.114 92.16V74.88C280.114 71.712 280.69 68.736 281.842 65.952C283.09 63.168 284.77 60.72 286.882 58.608C288.994 56.496 291.442 54.864 294.226 53.712C297.01 52.464 299.986 51.84 303.154 51.84V63.36Z"></path>
          <path d="M314.859 92.16V0H326.379V51.84H349.419V63.36H326.379V92.16C326.379 95.328 327.483 98.064 329.691 100.368C331.995 102.576 334.731 103.68 337.899 103.68H349.419V115.2H337.899C334.731 115.2 331.755 114.624 328.971 113.472C326.187 112.224 323.739 110.544 321.627 108.432C319.515 106.32 317.835 103.872 316.587 101.088C315.435 98.304 314.859 95.328 314.859 92.16Z"></path>
          <path d="M365.051 92.16C365.051 95.328 366.155 98.064 368.363 100.368C370.667 102.576 373.403 103.68 376.571 103.68H388.091C391.259 103.68 393.947 102.576 396.155 100.368C398.459 98.064 399.611 95.328 399.611 92.16V86.4H365.051V92.16ZM411.131 92.16C411.131 95.328 410.507 98.304 409.259 101.088C408.107 103.872 406.475 106.32 404.363 108.432C402.251 110.544 399.803 112.224 397.019 113.472C394.235 114.624 391.259 115.2 388.091 115.2H376.571C373.403 115.2 370.427 114.624 367.643 113.472C364.859 112.224 362.411 110.544 360.299 108.432C358.187 106.32 356.507 103.872 355.259 101.088C354.107 98.304 353.531 95.328 353.531 92.16V74.88H399.611C399.611 71.712 398.459 69.024 396.155 66.816C393.947 64.512 391.259 63.36 388.091 63.36H359.291V51.84H388.091C391.259 51.84 394.235 52.464 397.019 53.712C399.803 54.864 402.251 56.496 404.363 58.608C406.475 60.72 408.107 63.168 409.259 65.952C410.507 68.736 411.131 71.712 411.131 74.88V92.16Z"></path>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is the circle also in the same svg? If so put the circle before the text group.

Comment: No the Circle is not in the same SVG, well the thing is i want the text group to be under the circle.

Comment: swap the order of the SVG fragments then.

Answer (score 0):

Just write svg code after logo code.

```html
<img src="http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c53e.png" style="width:200px;" alt="Logo">
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" id="line">
        <g fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" fill-opacity="0" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
          <path d="M11.52 0V92.16C11.52 95.04 12.096 97.248 13.248 98.784C14.496 100.32 15.84 101.472 17.28 102.24C19.008 103.104 20.928 103.584 23.04 103.68H57.6V115.2H23.04C17.28 115.2 12.816 114 9.648 111.6C6.576 109.2 4.32 106.56 2.88 103.68C1.152 100.32 0.192 96.48 0 92.16V0H11.52Z" fill="white"/>
          <path d="M79.1606 92.16C79.1606 95.328 80.2646 98.064 82.4726 100.368C84.7766 102.576 87.5126 103.68 90.6806 103.68H102.201C105.369 103.68 108.057 102.576 110.265 100.368C112.569 98.064 113.721 95.328 113.721 92.16V86.4H79.1606V92.16ZM125.241 92.16C125.241 95.328 124.617 98.304 123.369 101.088C122.217 103.872 120.585 106.32 118.473 108.432C116.361 110.544 113.913 112.224 111.129 113.472C108.345 114.624 105.369 115.2 102.201 115.2H90.6806C87.5126 115.2 84.5366 114.624 81.7526 113.472C78.9686 112.224 76.5206 110.544 74.4086 108.432C72.2966 106.32 70.6166 103.872 69.3686 101.088C68.2166 98.304 67.6406 95.328 67.6406 92.16V74.88H113.721C113.721 71.712 112.569 69.024 110.265 66.816C108.057 64.512 105.369 63.36 102.201 63.36H73.4006V51.84H102.201C105.369 51.84 108.345 52.464 111.129 53.712C113.913 54.864 116.361 56.496 118.473 58.608C120.585 60.72 122.217 63.168 123.369 65.952C124.617 68.736 125.241 71.712 125.241 74.88V92.16Z" fill="white"/>
          <path d="M181.08 92.16V74.88C181.08 71.712 179.928 69.024 177.624 66.816C175.416 64.512 172.728 63.36 169.56 63.36H158.04C154.872 63.36 152.136 64.512 149.832 66.816C147.624 69.024 146.52 71.712 146.52 74.88V92.16C146.52 95.328 147.624 98.064 149.832 100.368C152.136 102.576 154.872 103.68 158.04 103.68H169.56C172.728 103.68 175.416 102.576 177.624 100.368C179.928 98.064 181.08 95.328 181.08 92.16ZM192.6 120.96C192.6 124.128 191.976 127.104 190.728 129.888C189.576 132.672 187.944 135.12 185.832 137.232C183.72 139.344 181.272 140.976 178.488 142.128C175.704 143.376 172.728 144 169.56 144H140.76V132.48H169.56C172.728 132.48 175.416 131.328 177.624 129.024C179.928 126.816 181.08 124.128 181.08 120.96V112.032C177.624 114.144 173.784 115.2 169.56 115.2H158.04C154.872 115.2 151.896 114.624 149.112 113.472C146.328 112.224 143.88 110.544 141.768 108.432C139.656 106.32 137.976 103.872 136.728 101.088C135.576 98.304 135 95.328 135 92.16V74.88C135 71.712 135.576 68.736 136.728 65.952C137.976 63.168 139.656 60.72 141.768 58.608C143.88 56.496 146.328 54.864 149.112 53.712C151.896 52.464 154.872 51.84 158.04 51.84H169.56C172.728 51.84 175.704 52.464 178.488 53.712C181.272 54.864 183.72 56.496 185.832 58.608C187.944 60.624 189.576 63.024 190.728 65.808C191.976 68.592 192.6 71.568 192.6 74.736V120.96Z"></path>
          <path d="M250.971 92.16V74.88C250.971 71.712 249.819 69.024 247.515 66.816C245.307 64.512 242.619 63.36 239.451 63.36H227.931C224.763 63.36 222.027 64.512 219.723 66.816C217.515 69.024 216.411 71.712 216.411 74.88V92.16C216.411 95.328 217.515 98.064 219.723 100.368C222.027 102.576 224.763 103.68 227.931 103.68H239.451C242.619 103.68 245.307 102.576 247.515 100.368C249.819 98.064 250.971 95.328 250.971 92.16ZM262.491 92.16C262.491 95.328 261.867 98.304 260.619 101.088C259.467 103.872 257.835 106.32 255.723 108.432C253.611 110.544 251.163 112.224 248.379 113.472C245.595 114.624 242.619 115.2 239.451 115.2H227.931C224.763 115.2 221.787 114.624 219.003 113.472C216.219 112.224 213.771 110.544 211.659 108.432C209.547 106.32 207.867 103.872 206.619 101.088C205.467 98.304 204.891 95.328 204.891 92.16V74.88C204.891 71.712 205.467 68.736 206.619 65.952C207.867 63.168 209.547 60.72 211.659 58.608C213.771 56.496 216.219 54.864 219.003 53.712C221.787 52.464 224.763 51.84 227.931 51.84H239.451C242.619 51.84 245.595 52.464 248.379 53.712C251.163 54.864 253.611 56.496 255.723 58.608C257.835 60.72 259.467 63.168 260.619 65.952C261.867 68.736 262.491 71.712 262.491 74.88V92.16Z"></path>
          <path d="M303.154 63.36C299.986 63.36 297.25 64.512 294.946 66.816C292.738 69.024 291.634 71.712 291.634 74.88V92.16C291.634 95.328 291.01 98.304 289.762 101.088C288.61 103.872 286.978 106.32 284.866 108.432C282.754 110.544 280.306 112.224 277.522 113.472C274.738 114.624 271.762 115.2 268.594 115.2V103.68C271.762 103.68 274.45 102.576 276.658 100.368C278.962 98.064 280.114 95.328 280.114 92.16V74.88C280.114 71.712 280.69 68.736 281.842 65.952C283.09 63.168 284.77 60.72 286.882 58.608C288.994 56.496 291.442 54.864 294.226 53.712C297.01 52.464 299.986 51.84 303.154 51.84V63.36Z"></path>
          <path d="M314.859 92.16V0H326.379V51.84H349.419V63.36H326.379V92.16C326.379 95.328 327.483 98.064 329.691 100.368C331.995 102.576 334.731 103.68 337.899 103.68H349.419V115.2H337.899C334.731 115.2 331.755 114.624 328.971 113.472C326.187 112.224 323.739 110.544 321.627 108.432C319.515 106.32 317.835 103.872 316.587 101.088C315.435 98.304 314.859 95.328 314.859 92.16Z"></path>
          <path d="M365.051 92.16C365.051 95.328 366.155 98.064 368.363 100.368C370.667 102.576 373.403 103.68 376.571 103.68H388.091C391.259 103.68 393.947 102.576 396.155 100.368C398.459 98.064 399.611 95.328 399.611 92.16V86.4H365.051V92.16ZM411.131 92.16C411.131 95.328 410.507 98.304 409.259 101.088C408.107 103.872 406.475 106.32 404.363 108.432C402.251 110.544 399.803 112.224 397.019 113.472C394.235 114.624 391.259 115.2 388.091 115.2H376.571C373.403 115.2 370.427 114.624 367.643 113.472C364.859 112.224 362.411 110.544 360.299 108.432C358.187 106.32 356.507 103.872 355.259 101.088C354.107 98.304 353.531 95.328 353.531 92.16V74.88H399.611C399.611 71.712 398.459 69.024 396.155 66.816C393.947 64.512 391.259 63.36 388.091 63.36H359.291V51.84H388.091C391.259 51.84 394.235 52.464 397.019 53.712C399.803 54.864 402.251 56.496 404.363 58.608C406.475 60.72 408.107 63.168 409.259 65.952C410.507 68.736 411.131 71.712 411.131 74.88V92.16Z"></path>
        </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Its looks nice but i want the Text Group to be under the Logo like this https://i.imgur.com/J9AEArI.png

Comment: Look on edited code. Please provide full code with logo.

Comment: In the code you've provided circle and logo didn't work. I see an empty page if I remove a part in <g> tag.